# How to create copies of Telegram X in Bluestacks on Mac

Tags: bluestacks, telegram

I am interested in creating multiple independent copies of Telegram X in Bluestacks Version 4.270.1 (2803) on Mac Big Sur 11.2.3.

The reason I want to do it is when there is a lot of accounts signed in in Telegram X it starts to lag a lot and crash too. I think that by creating multiple version of the app and signing in with less accounts in each this problem could be fixed.

To do the copying itself, I had already tried some popular methods suggested by google such as downloading an app in Google Store in Bluestocks that allows to manage multiple sessions of the same app, but (a) it doesn't work and (b) I don't think it's exactly what I need. By it doesn't work I mean whatever app like this I download, when I try to do something with it, it crashes most of the time.

Could you please recommend an elegant way to do this if there is any? I guess, the option of the last resort is just creating multiple Bluestacks right? However, this will probably cause issues with local memory on my laptop pretty quickly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use App Cloner to create multiple packages of Telegram X. Please beware that you might need the premium version for a lot of useful features in the service.

https://appcloner.app/